# Is it possible to convert Telerik test studio tests to selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, telerik

After a change of tooling, we now have a combination of Telerik test studio tests and selenium tests.

Is it possible to covert Telerik test studio into Selenium WebDriver tests?

Comment: How did you write the tests in Test Studio? Coded using C# or using their record feature?

Comment: @ChrisKenst Some coded, some recorded.

Answer (score 3):

Converting Telerik Test Studio cases into Selenium WebDriver will require a lot of rework, because Test Studio uses completely different technology, framework and syntax for example you find logic expression are different.

The only benefit you can get if you have used Nunit in both Test Studio and Selenium WebDriver, as both tools are compatible with Nunit, when you write code in Test Studio it asks for template and you can choose either of following:-

1. MbUnit
2. NUnit
3. VsUnit
4. xUnit

once you select template is converts recorded steps into code using C# and **TelerikTestingFramework** i.e. ArtOfTest.WebAii, which is totally different framework used in Selenium. But using **NUnit + C#** in both tools will make your work easier.

In short there is no shortcut to convert Test Studio cases in Selenium, it may require a lot of work, depending upon

1. How many cases you need to convert
2. How complex are you test cases
3. For how long you require these test cases *(if you know that you need to execute them only 2 more times and you have valid license of Test Studio till that time, you can live with two different platform test cases)*

One more hurdle for you is mixture of Recorded and coded test cases in Test Studio, as recorded test cases can only be executed in Test Studio standalone version, VSTS plugin or using run time edition of Test Studio. Selenium can't execute your Test Studio's recorded cases. In addition to it, ask to Telerik Support team too for help, their support center is good and reply well on time.

You first need to analyze the effort you have to put in for converting test cases, and your effort if you freshly write down these test cases in Selenium and then decide which option you should choose.

But if you choose to convert them, just keep on taking backup at regular intervals and define your strategy of conversion, don't go for converting all test cases in one go; **categorize them in groups (may be based on priority/complexity/size)** and then execute your strategy by targeting one sample of test cases at a time. This will give a clear indication about the coverage and amount of cases converted/ remaining.